# Code not redirecting when meant to

Tags: php, redirect

Can anyone work out why my code won't redirect, it was working two or three days ago, now it's not redirecting when it's meant to..
The full code is here:http://pastebin.com/ib0uQvQ7

Main part to look at

```
    <?php  
   /*------------includes--------------*/
   include ('./includes/connections.php');
   include ('./includes/brain_file.php');
   include ('./includes/style_top.php');
   /*------------includes--------------*/
    if($pl['my_jail'] > gmtime() || $pl['my_hosp'] > gmtime())
    {
    echo "<center><hr width='75%'/>Sorry this page is not viewable while in jail or hospital!<hr width='75%'/></center>";
    include ('./includes/style_bottom.php');
    exit();
    }
   if($_GET['action']) {
   if(!in_array($_GET['action'], array('interview','quit','promote','special'))) {
   echo "<center>Invalid action!</center>";
   include ('./includes/style_bottom.php');
   exit();
   }
   }
   $_GET['action'] = isset($_GET['action']) && ctype_alpha($_GET['action']) ? trim($_GET['action']) : 'index';
   switch($_GET['action'])
   {
   case 'interview':
   job_interview();
   break;

   case 'quit':
   quit_job();
   break;

   case 'special':
   job_specials();
   break;

   case 'promote':
   promote_me();
   break;

   default:
   job_index();
   break;
   }
   function job_index()
  {
   global $pl;
   $job = array();
   $q_ry = array();
   $q_ry = "SELECT `my_job`,`my_job_rank`,`armypoints`,`grocpoints`,`casipoints`,
                  `medipoints`,`educpoints`,`lawpoints`,`my_comp`
           FROM `members_extra`
           WHERE `playerid` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['playerid'])."'";
   $job = mysql_query($q_ry);
   $job = mysql_fetch_array($job);
   if(!$job['my_job']) {

   if(!$job['my_job'] && !$job['my_comp'])
  {
   header('location:newspaper.php?page=jobs');
    }
    else
       {
   header('location:companies.php');
  }


    }
```

Comment: Is there any error printed or logged?

Comment: No there's not, why is that?

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Refresh:0; url=companies.php");
```

Comment: I will try this soon. Do I change it with both headers?

Comment: I changed it and nothing

Comment: First file php copy.
header("Refresh:0; url=companies.php");

Comment: <?php
header("Refresh:0; url=companies.php");
///...........
?>
likely error type syntax;

Comment: But now all of a sudden it stopped working, and I haven't changed a thing within my code

Comment: And also do I replace the header Location with the refresh??